# How does Thor get back to Earth, again?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, marvel, thor-marvel, the-avengers-2012

In the *The Avengers*, there is a post-credits scene where Thor returns to Asgard and then a **post**-post-credits scene (!) where the Avengers eat shawarma together.

[image]

If Thor left, then how does he return to Earth especially given that...

> ...the Bifrost Bridge was destroyed in the movie *Thor (2011)*, and it required a prohibitively immense amount of power to send him there in the first place.

Comment: I tried to edit in some information for my duplicate question here: scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28701/how-did-thor-return-for-shawarma but I'm not sure what else could be added

Comment: My interpretation was that the first post-credits scene was the "real" one, i.e. the one that actually hints at what happened after the events of the movie. The second post-credits scene was just the punchline to an in-movie joke.

Comment: I suppose I can be persuaded to change the answer of a 2.5 year old question because pictures.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As you can see from [this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Otr.jpg) on Joyreactor, Tony saw the Shawarma Palace (later seen at the end of the credits) *during* the [Battle of New York](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_New_York).

Given that the owners are cleaning up the broken glass in the background, it seems most likely that the ***post***-post-credit scene is supposed to take place **immediately** after the battle (e.g. before Thor left for Asgard) rather than at some undefined point in the future.

[image]

The [Iron Man 3 Prelude comic](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel's_Iron_Man_3_Prelude_Vol_1_1) shows that the Shawarma scene took place approximately **one hour** after the attack.

[image]

Comment: Crash-landing next to a business == noticing it? It's a fun little easter egg, but arguably a stretch to say that he's paying attention to the restaurants nearby after evading/destroying an alien warship and nearly killing himself in the process.

Comment: @phantom42 - it strikes me that Tony Stark is the sort of person who would notice that sort of thing, especially if he's hungry :-)

Comment: I'd expect him to notice it more if there was a beautiful woman standing nearby.

Comment: @phantom42 - Well that absolutely goes without saying...

Comment: IIRC, Tony spotting the schawarma place is mentioned in the director's commentary.

Comment: @Keen - I'll take your word for that one.

Comment: I don't buy this; all that comic shows is that Rhodes showed up an hour after Tony invited him. The scene in the movie could have been immediately after the first comic panel, or immediately before it, or ages before it, or ages after it.

Comment: @lightningracisinobrit - You seem to be ignoring the top left box. Tony asks him to get there ASAP. The battle takes just under one hour, then Rhodes turns up, having just missed all the excitement (which is the joke). What's not to "buy"?

Comment: @Richard: I'm not ignoring anything, but I dispute your interpretation. There is nothing in here that proves an hour passed between the battle and the post-post-credits scene. Nothing! For one, the post-post-credits scene is not even _in_ the comic extract (it could have taken place ages before, or ages after — Rhodes had not recently shown up in the post-post-credits scene; indeed, he wasn't even _there_), and for another thing you do not know when during the battle the top left box takes place _if it takes place during the battle at all_. I think you're really jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - I think your point is (semi-valid) but there isn't any other way to read it when you read the full comic. Tony calls Rhodes at the start of the battle. Rhodes says he's about an hour away but will obviously gets there as soon as possible. He arrives, only to find the fighting finished. That is **literally the joke.**

Comment: _"Tony calls Rhodes at the start of the battle."_ That's the missing information. Even so, you're not strictly on target even with this information, because the battle lasted _X_ minutes, and that eats into Rhody's hour-long travel time! :P If the battle lasted 50 minutes then this comic suggests the post-post-credit scene (remember, that's before Rhodes arrives) was set anywhere up to just _10 minutes_ after the battle. I really don't think you can draw the conclusions you're drawing, just thinking logically.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - I'm happy to concede that it may have been slightly earlier or later. Note my use of the word approximately...

Comment: @phantom42 - Stark is a genius who is constantly multitasking. Even when he's paying attention to a conversation at hand, he's off with the faeries, thinking up a new invention or noticing minuscule details in the world around him. The Galaga scene in Avengers would be another good example of this. Thus I don't think him noticing a Shawarma place in the midst of a battle would be much of a stretch.

Answer (score 34):

There is no specific indication of how much time has passed between the end of the battle and the story wrap-up.

Although Tony mentioned

> going to the schwarma restaurant "next week"

the disheveled state of the restaurant and exhausted looks on the heroes gave me the impression that the scene took place between the end of the battle and

> before Thor and Loki returned to Asgard.

Comment: That's what I assumed; the scenes are just shown in reverse order.

Comment: I will accept this answer, but I was really interested in a consistent theory that allowed enough time for Chris Evans to grow facial hair (although it was covered by a prosthesis, which explains why his hand is on his jaw for the entire shot).

Comment: The fact that they were going out of their way to hide the facial hair indicates that the facial hair is not supposed to be considered canon. That aside though - again, there is no real indication of how much time passes between any of the events. Some guys just grow beards in a few days.

Comment: And Thor being a manly god, might be able to grow a beard while you watch!

Comment: Chris Evan's facial hair was for another movie role that he was either preparing to film, or had started to film when they got the idea for this post-credit scene. Captain America was not meant to have facial hair, hence the fist over his face as @phantom42 pointed out.

Comment: @krillgar I believe the film was *Snowpiercer*, where Evans has a mighty beard.