# How did Thor return for Shawarma?

Tags: marvel, avengers, thor-marvel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Thor get back to Earth, again?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/how-does-thor-get-back-to-earth-again)

At the end of the Avengers film Iron Man!Tony Stark expresses his desire for post-world-saving Shawarma, regrettably however he has other affairs to attend to (ensuring Loki is returned to Asgard).

However in the post-post-film scene we see the Avengers meeting up for Shawarma, *below*

[image]

How does Thor return to earth? Has he been sent back to help protect earth? Or is this scene meant to precede Thor's return to earth?

Answer (score 16):

It would make the most sense for this scene to have occured before everyone left, for a few reasons:

- Everyone is present, including Thor. Remember that everyone hopped in separate cars and drove off in different directions, but Tony Stark mentioned that the Shawarma restaurant was round the corner.
- Everyone is still in the combat gear they wore during battle.
- The restaurant is a total mess from the destruction, but during the scene where everyone drives away at the end the city seems to have been cleaned up.

All in all, it wouldn't make much sense for them to pack up, go their separate ways, then come back and get changed into their combat gear again just to visit Shawarma. The only question I can't answer is who's looking after Loki - I can only imagine that various SHIELD operatives have him in a similar cage to the one intended to hold Hulk.

Comment: Loki was never in the custody between his defeat and being extradited, was he?

Comment: I would have thought he was, since he was in shackles when Thor used the Tesseract to return him to their realm.

Comment: [(reference for him being in shackles)](http://i.imgur.com/yQJ3R.jpg)

Comment: i think Loki was in ICU getting his bones patched up after the "HULK-SMASH"

Comment: Where were they when Thor and Loki left?