# Where was War Machine?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, iron-man, iron-man-2

In Iron Man 2 we see that [War Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Machine) was able to fight very well. He provides support for Iron Man but when Manhattan was in danger (in Avengers) where was he? Then in Iron Man 3 he comes back from nowhere.

**I want to know that where was he and why didn't he show up when the world was invaded???**

Comment: This answer to this question also provides an answer to this; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/how-does-thor-get-back-to-earth-again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Iron Man 3 Prequel comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel%27s_Iron_Man_3_Prelude_Vol_1) deal with this. War Machine was fighting some bad dudes in Asia when the attack happened. First he had to deal with them, then he had to travel to America to assist with the invasion.

By the time he arrived, the team was already sitting down to a well-deserved Shawarma...

[image]

[image]

Comment: No offence intended to the artist, but Captain America, Hawkeye and Bruce Banner look almost identical there.

Comment: ...and this Stark looks nothing like Robert Downey Jr.  Romanoff and Thor are pretty accurate, but... yeah.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - Everyone's a critic ;-)